# Testing controllers in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mocking

What is the best method to test controllers in ASP MVC? (mocking frameworks, IoC, Selenium/Watir/Watin ...)

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040 read this book, that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing MVC controllers would fall into the Unit Tests when you look at the Test Pyramid. I personally prefer the following tools for Unit Testing:

- NUnit - Because it's a far more mature testing framework when compared to MSTest and there's a lot of useful add-ons that integrate with it such as Resharper.
- Moq is a good .NET Framework Mocking Library
- Unity is a great Dependency Injection framework which you can download from Codeplex and supports Constructor, Property and Method injection.

As far as writing code for automated browser testing goes, I have had experience with WebDriver is a great tool, however I classify automated browser tests as acceptance tests and hence less related to testing MVC Controllers in isolation.

Another great tool for Acceptance Testing is SpecFlow which is definitely worth a look if you need to do Acceptance Testing and works very nicely in an Agile environment.

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing personally I use the [MvcContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) which is based on Rhino Mocks. The whole HTTP is mocked and it provides some nice extension methods allowing to assert on the different results.

Comment: This is what we do.  More often than not though, we don't test our controller actions (as a result, we push almost all logic into other service calls, mappers, etc so they can be tested).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Test Project while creating the MVC project, by selecting the checkbox to add Test Project. Once Test Project is created, right click on the project and add a reference to the MVC project. After it’s added, we need to add a reference of System.Web.Mvc in the test project by right clicking on the test project and selecting Manage Nuget Package. From the Nuget Package Manager, you can install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc in the test project.

[image]

As a last step to setup the Test Project, right click and add a class named HomeControllerTest.  In the newly created class, write a sample test method as shown in the listing below.

```
public class HomeControllerTest
{
[TestMethod]
    public void SampleTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("HomeController", "HomeController");
    }
}
```

Now you’re ready to build the test project and you should not get any build errors. We have written the sample test method comparing two strings, and to run the test, simply select Test->Windows->Test Explorer as shown in the image below.

[image]

In the Test Explorer, you will find SampleTest listed there. To run the test, either right click on the test and select run, or click on the Run right on the top of the test. In this example we ran the SampleTest, which is passed! You can see Passed Tests in the Test Explorer as shown in the image below:

[image]

See the full sample at the below link :

https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-controllers